# Проверка на отправку писем

Tags: php, phpmailer

Добрый вечер, есть скрипт, который отправляет письмо по окончанию регистрации. **Как проверить, смог ли отправить скрипт письмо?** В данном скрипте, если ввести несуществующий адрес, к примеру, `sddfgdfg@sdgdfg.dfggd`(такого адреса действительно не существует, от Gmail приходит об этом ответ), то пишет, что письмо отправлено:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPOptions = array ( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false, 
'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true)); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'моя почта@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'Password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = 'моя почта@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName ='отправитель';
$mail->addAddress( sddfgdfg@sdgdfg.dfggd,'');
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $theme;
$mail->Body = $text;
$mail->AltBody = 'это альтернативное письмо';

//$mail->SMTPDebug =4;

if($mail->send()){
echo 'письмо отправлено';

}else{
echo 'письмо НЕ ОТПРАВЛЕНО';
echo 'ошибка:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что это несуществующий адрес? Письмо отправлено, принято на обработку gmail.com, уведомление о том, что письмо не удалось доставить должно упасть на ящик отправителя.

Comment: vp_arth, Gmail сказал, который не отправил Сообщению адресату dfhfgh@sdgfdfg.sdfgfg не доставлено, так как домен sddfgdfg@sdgdfg.dfggd не найден. Удалите пробелы, исправьте опечатки и повторите попытку.

Comment: Ну так, а я о чём написал? Если gmail о нём узнал, стало быть письмо было ему отправлено.

Comment: vp_arth, каким образом????? если написано же что не отправлено и не найден

Comment: Кем написано? Вы понимаете где ваш скрипт, а где gmail?

Comment: Вы можете написать отдельный воркер, который читает входящие и принимает решения по не доставленным сообщениям..

Comment: использую gmail как SMTP, надо что бы так же и скрипт выдавал сообщение. Вот более точное сообщение от gmail DNS Error: 20112491 DNS type 'mx' lookup of sdgfdfg.sdfgfg responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: sdgfdfg.sdfgfg

Comment: @Юрий а вы можете получать такие ошибки от gmail своим скриптом? Если да, то любая ошибка свидетельствует о недоставке письма

Comment: Письмо отправлено, а то что происходит на стороне gmail - не проблемы скрипта. К слову, точно так же работает и почтовый клиент - он отправить письмо, а потом уже вам придет ПИСЬМО (опять же), что адреса нету.